# Page is hanging on selecting configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I moved my Shop from Debian 8 to 9 with PHP7.
Now I have a problem with configurable products...when I select a Color.....I can only see the Ajax Loader Gif...and nothing is happening.
I have to reload the page.

regards